# nav-bar in wordpress is not displayed to mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, menu, navbar, responsive

I have create nav bar as they describe to [Convert Bootstrap navbar to WordPress menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332527/convert-bootstrap-navbar-to-wordpress-menu)
I can see the menu in desktop but the menu is not displayed in mobile devices.
In mobile devices I can see the button where the menu will be displayed but the menu is not displayed.

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="nav navbar-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
     ?>
 </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: try checking for any js errors in `console`.

Comment: the only error that i get is the following 
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.0

Comment: any link for the website??

Comment: it is in a localhost :(

Comment: Can you check the above code please?I think that I have done errors in class names and navs.

Comment: try adding id `'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',` and in `data-target` add `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`

Comment: Now I can see the "Toggle navigation" in mobile menu, but the menu items are not displayed.

Comment: everything is fine!!!

Comment: @stavroch how did you come to resolve it?